# How to update style when a window is scaled in angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have a chat window on my app and I want to update the size of an image in this chat window when the chat window is less than a certain width. Is there a way I can update the css style or class based on the width?

I'm using typescript and have the value of my cat window passed in:

```
@Input()
public chatWidth: number;
```

In my html, I was attempting to do something like this where I would apply a css class if the chatWidth property was less than 400:

```
<img *ngIf="upsell?.image?.url; let url" [src]="url" ng-class="{bigger-img : chatWidth < 400}">
```

However, this doesn't work and I don't seem to even get an error in my console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<img *ngIf="upsell?.image?.url; let url" [src]="url" [ngClass]="{'bigger-img': chatWidth < 400}">
```

More info [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#how-to-use) on `ngClass`.

**UPDATE**

You can, I believe, wrap the condition in a 'method' that returns a `boolean` defined in your respective component and call it in the template instead of directly declaring it in the template. Here, in your case,

in component.ts,

```
checkChatWidth(): boolean {
  return this.chatWidth < 400;
}
```

then, in your template,

```
<img *ngIf="upsell?.image?.url; let url" [src]="url" [ngClass]="{'bigger-img': checkChatWidth()}">
```

You have to take care of the possible 'null' checks within your 'method' that may arise due to not having a value for the 'chatWidth' input property based on your code setup.

Comment: is it possible to do this in a typescript/javascript function instead? I just realized that I would want to position other things too and it may look nicer doing this logic somewhere else instead of in my html template

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope that will help in you in the right direction.